# How to capture bootstrap drop down close event in angular 8, on click of outside of drop down

Tags: html, css, angular8

I am using Angular 8 with the Azia theme (bootstrap 4 theme). I want to capture the close event of the dropdown when I click outside of the dropdown. In the below code snippet that **show** class needs to be added conditionally to hide/show dropdown. below code not working at one condition that is the outside click of dropdown due to default behavior of a theme. double click is needed to open dropdown. so i want to capture event when css changes of dropdown.

Here is my code.

```
  <div (click)="isShowDropDown != isShowDropDown" #notification id="noti"
  [ngClass]="isShowDropDown ? 'dropdown az-header-notification cursor-pointer show' : 'dropdown az- 
  header-notification cursor-pointer'">

  // code here to show dropdown content.

  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved this problem with the angular property binding method instead of [ngClass].

solution is,

In HTML.

```
<div (click)="showNotification()" 
  id="unreadNotificationdropdown" [class]="showNotificationDropdownClass">
   <app-drop-down-content></app-drop-down-content>
</div>
```

Declared variables in class.

```
  isShowDropDown: boolean =false;
  this.showNotificationDropdownClass:string = 'dropdown az-header-notification cursor-pointer tx-24';
```

In componet.ts

```
  showNotification() {
  if (document.getElementById('unreadNotificationdropdown').className.search('show') 
    === -1 && this.isShowDropDown) {
    this.showNotificationDropdownClass = 'dropdown az-header-notification cursor- 
    pointer show tx-24 ';
  } else {
    this.isShowDropDown = !this.isShowDropDown;
    if (this.isShowDropDown) {
      this.showNotificationDropdownClass = 'dropdown az-header-notification cursor-pointer show tx-24';
    } else {
      this.showNotificationDropdownClass = 'dropdown az-header-notification cursor-pointer tx-24';
      }
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use (focusout) or (blur) events.

These two events are fired when an element  loses focus.

The main difference between `blur` and `focusout` is that `focusout` bubbles while blur does not.

Please take a look at this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rzkbwe?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) it uses focusout.

Comment: I tried this solution, but the focus out event is not fired when I clicked outside. Actually in my code (refer above code). Dropdown content is loaded from another component. 
 inside that main div of the dropdown . is this creates problem to catch focus out event

Comment: @purnimakamble i think the event is fired but you have to make an event emitter that inform the parent about loosing the focus of it's child.

Comment: Blur and focusout events work for focus-able elements. For div's they won't work unless tabindex is set.